# Disable warnings in Ruby - where to place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm using Ruby -v 2.2.4 currently and don't want to upgrade to 2.3.1 for compatibility purposes. However, I'm now getting hit with these warning messages.

```
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy. 
(To disable warnings, set RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1)
```

Where do I place that code?

```
--> set RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1)
```

Comment: Environment variable...

Answer (score 2):

It's depend on the OS which you use, for Linux(and MacOS) and bash shell you can place it:

- [`Bash shell`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)
- Before command e.g. `$user: RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1 irb`
- [`Export as env variable`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)

[`For windows read this.`](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the quick reply - I'm on MacOS. Still having issues though. Could you be more specific as to how to do it? I still don't understand where to put it?